# Using AzureLogHandler and AzureEventHandler together

Tags: python, azure

I want to use  AzureLogHandler and AzureEventHandler together it in one file how to use it?  But it will print both places traces and customEvents, which is a waste of resources

```
import logging
from opencensus.ext.azure.log_exporter import AzureLogHandler, AzureEventHandler


EXTRA_INFO = {'custom_dimensions': {'info': 'This is test'}}
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logEvent = logging.getLogger(__name__)


azureEventHandler = AzureEventHandler(
        connection_string=f'InstrumentationKey={INSTRUMENTATION_KEY}')
azureEventHandler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
logEvent.addHandler(azureEventHandler)

azureLogHandler =AzureLogHandler(
    connection_string=f'InstrumentationKey={INSTRUMENTATION_KEY}')
azureLogHandler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

logger.addHandler(azureLogHandler)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)



def main():
    for i in range(10):
        logger.info(str(i) + ":logger  info Info Log", extra=EXTRA_INFO)
        logEvent.info(str(i) + ":logEvent  info Info Log", extra=EXTRA_INFO)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Hi, can you tell exactly what do you want to achieve and what is the blocker? Because it seems like you have already created 2 different loggers and they can be used as you want to use them.